JSDoc not appearing on the returned object of a function
In my TypeScript project, I've got a React Hook and would like to include some handy JSDoc for the next dev. My function returns an object with methods, and I've noticed that the function and the methods all have the proper JSDoc, but the object itself isn't populating with any.
Example
testHook.ts
/**
 * @returns A `UseTestHookController` used to control a thing
 */
export function useTestHook(): UseTestHookController {
    return {
        start() {
            console.log('starting the thing!')
        },
        end() {
            console.log('ending the thing..')
        },
    }
}

/**
 * Provides methods to start and stop a thing
 */
interface UseTestHookController {
    /**
     * Starts the thing
     */
    start: () => void
    /**
     * Ends the thing
     */
    end: () => void
}

main.ts
import { useTestHook } from '@/testHook'

const controller = useTestHook()
controller.start()
controller.end()

In the above example, useTestHook(), start(), and end() will provide the hover tips that I defined previously. However, the controller object just shows this (instead of "Provides methods to start and stop a thing" like I defined above):
const controller: UseTestHookController

It's not wrong, but is there a way I can get UseTestHookController's JSDoc description to appear on hover?
Things I've Tried

Closing / Reopening VSCode
Defining JSDoc within the function instead of using an interface

/**
 * @returns A `UseTestHookController` used to control a thing
 */
export function useTestHook() {
    /**
     * Provides methods to start and stop a thing
     */
    const controller = {
        /**
         * Starts the thing
         */
        start() {
            console.log('starting the thing!')
        },
        /**
         * Ends the thing
         */
        end() {
            console.log('ending the thing..')
        },
    }
    return controller
}

Here, the hover tip for controller (when used in main.ts) looks like this:
const controller: {
    start(): void;
    end(): void;
}


Returning the object directly

/**
 * @returns A `UseTestHookController` used to control a thing
 */
export function useTestHook() {
    /**
     * Provides methods to start and stop a thing
     */
    return {
        /**
         * Starts the thing
         */
        start() {
            console.log('starting the thing!')
        },
        /**
         * Ends the thing
         */
        end() {
            console.log('ending the thing..')
        },
    }
}

Hover tooltip just shows the object's properties, like the previous.

Am I missing something? Is this how it's meant to work, or maybe VSCode is just bunk?
